# Websocket HTML5 create onmessage function similar to socket.IO .on function

Tags: javascript, websocket, frontend

I tried without success to modify WebSocket.onmessage function for being able add a switch case dynamically:

```
socket.onmessage = function (event) {

  let message = JSON.parse(event.data) 

  switch(event.type) { 

  case "UPDATE_USER": 
    // update user
  case "UPDATE_FOO": 
   // update FOO
  case "UPDATE_BAR": 
  // update FOO

}
```

Socket.IO is doing what I am trying to implement with the .on function:

```
socket.on('ADD_NEW_DYNAMIC_CASE', (data) => {
  // update socket with another action case
});
```

Socket.io is capable of updating the equivalent of onmessage function by adding a listener to any message.type you will receive.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What are you trying to do? What events does the `onmessage` handle? what did you try so far?

Comment: please edit your question. It’s very hard to read your comment and the information really belongs in the question.

Comment: I just updated my message, thanks for your help !

Comment: Where are you stuck? What isn't working? What's the error you get in the console? As far as I can see your approach seems sound enough (except that I wouldn't use a `switch` statement).

Comment: Everything is working, it's just about adding a new case dynamically. Right now I have X case, If i want to add X+1 case dynamically, with Socket.IO it is very easy I just use there API socket.on and then a new case is added. However with the HTML5 WebSocket I wont be able to add a new case dynamically, like adding a new case from another function for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you need is to dynamically add cases to a switch statement, you might be better off using a map pattern instead of a switch statement.

The switch statement can't be updated dynamically (without meta-programming and rewriting the whole function), while a map pattern is quite simple to implement.

Consider this:

```
socket = {};
socket.onmessage = function (event) {
  try {
    var message = JSON.parse(event.data);
    if(this[message.type] && (typeof this[message.type] == "function"))
      this[message.type](message);
    else
      console.error("Unknown event:", message);
  }
  catch(error) {
    console.error("Invalid JSON", error, event);
  }
}.bind(socket)
// example: 
socket.fire = (msg) => { console.log( "I'm on fire!" ); }
socket.onmessage({data: "{\"type\": \"fire\"}"});
```

Thie approach will allow you to dynamically add events by defining functions that handle them and without worrying about the switch statement.

This will also allow you to define a "catch-all" event handler for unknown events.